# Google apps script, How to create a trigger in another file with the ID?

Tags: google-apps-script, triggers

I'm trying to create both an onEdit and an onChange trigger in another spreadsheet where I have the ID of the spreadsheet.

I've tried messing around with the provided code in the installable triggers section of the [developers guide](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/projects)

```
function createEditTrigger() {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.openById('Insert file ID HEre');
  ScriptApp.newTrigger('myFunction')
      .forSpreadsheet(ss)
      .onEdit()
      .create();
}
```

I expected this to create the trigger in the other file but it ends up just creating it in the current file.

Comment: Try passing `ss.getId()` instead.

Comment: @TheMaster I'm not sure I understand, where should I put the ss.getId(). I've tried putting it in all of the logical places, i think.

Comment: Try `forSpreadsheet(/*ID here*/)`. If it doesn't work, I got nothing.

Comment: @TheMaster I've had an idea that might be a bit of a long shot but it may work. If I name a function onOpen I think that I read somewhere that sheets will pick up that it is an onOpen function and trigger on open even if you havn't set up a trigger. If I created one of these to check if the triggers for that file were corect and if they werent then create the appropriate ones. is my underlying assumption correct or not?

Comment: unloss of course the onOpen function doesnt have the permissions required to create triggers

Comment: Simple onOpen()  won't have permission to create triggers.. It'll have permission to addMenu items.